# How to tag hotjar videos automatically using Javascript

Tags: hotjar

I'm trying to tag our Hotjar recordings automatically from within google optimize so we can more easily identify A or B users. The problem is that I can't find anywhere that explains how to do this, the [official documentation](https://help.hotjar.com/hc/en-us/articles/115011819488-Tagging-Recordings) explains that you *can* do this, just not how to do it, it only goes on to explain how to do it manually.

How do you use javascript to automatically tag a Hotjar recording?

Comment: I think the documentation has been updated to include explanation for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**From the official [documentation](https://help.hotjar.com/hc/en-us/articles/115011819488-Tagging-Recordings):**

> Recordings can be automatically tagged using a JavaScript code
>   snippet. If your visitor visits any page which runs this JavaScript
>   code, their Recording will be saved with the tag/s you set. To tag a
>   Recording, add this JavaScript code:

```
hj('tagRecording', ['tag1', 'tag2']);
```

> Doing so will cause all Recordings of visitors who pass through this
>   page to include the two tags "tag1" and "tag2".

> **Important**
>
> If there is a chance that the code will be run before the
>   Hotjar script has loaded, you must add this line of code just before.

```
window.hj=window.hj||function(){(hj.q=hj.q||[]).push(arguments)};
```